# Manutenção prevista agendada para o sábado 17 de março as 13:00h UTC

Tags: debate, status-pronto

Como [esta publicação no Meta Stack Exchange indica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307744/planned-maintenance-scheduled-for-march-17-2018-at-1300-utc-9am-us-eastern), teremos um grande evento de manutenção que fará com que nosso site esteja em status somente leitura por um tempo no sábado, 17 de março às 13:00 UTC. Após a conclusão da atualização, retornaremos ao normal.

Estamos planejando que o evento aconteça em uma hora ou menos. A publicação original tem mais informações.